# Inherit from scipy.sparse.csr_matrix class

Tags: python, scipy, subclass, sparse-matrix

I want to augment the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` class with a few methods and replace a few others for personal use. I am making a child class which inherits from `csr_matrix`, as such:

```
class SparseMatrix(sp.csr_matrix):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(matrix)
```

This won't work though, throwing:

> AttributeError: toSpa not found

Could you please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Somewhere in the SciPy Sparse Matrix implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a9fb36bc44bad4bbd2c1a41cb43c6f10925b38ae/scipy/sparse/base.py#L70) the first three letters of the class name are used to define a method that will do the transformations among the different sparse matrix types  ([see this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scipy-user/-1PIkEMFWd8/r7QziChd_WoJ)). Therefore, you have to implement using a name like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

class csr_matrix_alt(csr_matrix):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(csr_matrix_alt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

s = csr_matrix_alt(np.random.random((10, 10)))
print(type(s))
#<class '__main__.csr_matrix_alt'>
```

Other names like `csr_mymatrix`, `csr_test` and so forth would be possible...

Comment: It looks like the three-letter code logic has changed. Here's a link to the line that picks out the first three letters, which was part of SciPy v0.16.1: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a9fb36bc44bad4bbd2c1a41cb43c6f10925b38ae/scipy/sparse/base.py#L70.